# Is there anyway to load/run a Blazor enabled web page from local disk?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

Is there anyway to load/run a Blazor enabled web page from local disk?

When I try, the browser cannot fetch the file `_framework/blazor.boot.json` from local disk. I wonder if there is a workaround?

[image]

I understand that I can achieve something similar by using ELectron.NET or PWA. With this question I like to learn about if I can make this working using a local disk access.